# Removing background using imagemagick, on a white product

Tags: imagemagick

Here's the original image I'm trying to remove background from:

[image]

I am trying to use imagemagick to remove the background from an image. When the image has a white product, my script doesn't work well. It removes the white from inside the product also. In brief I'm trying to do the following

- create a mask image (replace background pixels with white with fuzz and threshold)
- apply the mask over the original image to generate the output

If I use a fuzz factor of 0, like shown below, i get the background removed, but it creates a nasty halo around it. What can be done here?

[image: This one is image with fuzz factor 0]

Comment: How about sharing the original image?

Comment: done that @MarkSetchell. Do you have any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take advantage of [HSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) colorspace, and create an alpha mask from the lightness channel.

```
convert tshirt.jpg \( \
        +clone -colorspace HSL -separate \
        -delete 0,1 -fx 'u>0.975?0:1' \) \
        -compose CopyOpacity -composite  \
        out.png
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a simple threshold to pick out the white and then some sort of filtration to remove the noise/ragged edges. So, for example

```
convert shirt.jpg -threshold 99.99% -negate  result.jpg
```

which gives this:

[image]

Then apply some median filtering to smooth it:

```
convert shirt.jpg -threshold 99.99% -median 5 -negate  result.jpg
```

[image]

or maybe a bigger filter:

```
convert shirt.jpg -threshold 99.99% -median 11 -negate  result.jpg
```

which gives this

[image]

Alternatively, you may get on better with an erosion and a dilation...

```
convert shirt.jpg -threshold 99.99% -negate  \
   -morphology erode  diamond:3              \
   -morphology dilate diamond:3 result.jpg
```

[image]

You may like to use Anthony Thyssen's `flicker_compare` to flicker between the input and result image to see what you have got, see [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/scripts/flicker_cmp).

```
./flickercompare -o flick.gif shirt.jpg result.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Mark, while this approach works well for white products. The images where a product isn't white, it creates a nasty jagged halo around it. Probably the erosion process does that. Also, it doesn't work on certain other kind of images at all.. is there an approach on background removal that should work on probably all kinds of images?

Comment: There would be nothing stopping you using my method for whitish products and a different method for coloured products. I don't have all that much time to devote to working out a method for all your images, maybe you can take the ideas from Eric on using `HSL` and some of my ideas about median filtering and morphology and experiment some more. Also, have a look at Anthony Thyssen's excellent pages here... http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#bg_remove